Sync Google Cloud Directory users to AD
Is there a way to sync Google Directory users to Active Directory (on-prem or extra ID) so that they can log in to domain-joined PCs?
It appears to me that GCDS only synchronizes users from AD to Google Cloud and not the other way around.
